# Message Type: rosjava subscriber problem

Tags: ros, message, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS community,

My problem seems pretty simple to fix, but since I'm new to ROS (and my java is a bit rusty) and I'm running into a few problems. Right now, all I'm doing is trying to create a subscriber node that will subscribe to the turtlebot's /odom message. Currently in my onNewMessage method, I have no code except a simple System.out.println("Well, at least I got something..."); To test if I successfully detect the message.

Unfortunately I never make it to that point in my code as I run into this guy:

> EXCEPTION:
> java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException)
> org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException:
> java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException

I'm positive that the /odom topic is running and can rostopic echo it just fine. Here is my code, I got it from the rosjava external documentation and modified it to try and accept the nav_msgs/Odometry type instead of a String. I got the original code here: http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/getting_started.html

```
package mypackagename;

import nav_msgs.Odometry;

import org.ros.message.MessageListener;
import org.ros.namespace.GraphName;
import org.ros.node.AbstractNodeMain;
import org.ros.node.ConnectedNode;
import org.ros.node.topic.Subscriber;

public class OdometryCollector extends AbstractNodeMain {
   public GraphName getDefaultNodeName() {
     return new GraphName("mypackagename/OdemetryCollector");
   }

   public void onStart(ConnectedNode connectedNode) {
      Subscriber<nav_msgs.Odometry> odomCollector =    connectedNode.newSubscriber("/odom", "nav_msgs/Odometry");
      odomCollector.addMessageListener(new MessageListener<nav_msgs.Odometry>() {
    
  public void onNewMessage(nav_msgs.Odometry arg0) {
         System.out.println("Well, At least I got something...");
  };
 });
 }
}
```

This is my console output with the --info option activated:

> Loading node class:
> robonav.OdometryCollector Jun 20, 2012
> 9:36:36 AM
> org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar
>  INFO: MasterXmlRpcEndpoint URI:
> http://192.168.0.24:11311 Jun 20, 2012
> 9:36:36 AM
> org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar
> onPublisherAdded INFO: Registering
> publisher:
> Publisher<PublisherDefinition<PublisherIdentifier<NodeIdentifier</robonav/OdemetryCollector,
> [http://192.168.0.226:39828/>](http://192.168.0.226:39828/%3E),
> TopicIdentifier>,
> Topic<TopicIdentifier,
> TopicDescription<rosgraph_msgs/Log,
> acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb>>>>
> Jun 20, 2012 9:36:36 AM
> org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar
> callMaster INFO: Response<Success,
> Registered
> [/robonav/OdemetryCollector] as
> publisher of [/rosout],
> [http://192.168.0.24:55348/]> Jun 20,
> 2012 9:36:36 AM
> org.ros.internal.node.topic.DefaultPublisher$1
> > onMasterRegistrationSuccess INFO:
> > Publisher registered:
> > Publisher<PublisherDefinition<PublisherIdentifier<NodeIdentifier</robonav/OdemetryCollector,
> > http://192.168.0.226:39828/>,
> > TopicIdentifier</rosout>>,
> > Topic<TopicIdentifier</rosout>,
> > TopicDescription<rosgraph_msgs/Log,
> > acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb>>>>
> > Jun 20, 2012 9:36:36 AM
> > org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar
> > onSubscriberAdded INFO: Registering
> > subscriber:
> > Subscriber<Topic<TopicIdentifier</odom>,
> > TopicDescription<nav_msgs/Odometry,
> > cd5e73d190d741a2f92e81eda573aca7>>>
> > Jun 20, 2012 9:36:36 AM
> > org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar
> > callMaster INFO: Response<Success,
> > Subscribed to [/odom],
> > [http://192.168.0.24:60375/]> Jun 20,
> > 2012 9:36:36 AM
> > org.ros.internal.node.topic.DefaultSubscriber$1
> onMasterRegistrationSuccess INFO:
> Subscriber registered:
> Subscriber<Topic<TopicIdentifier,
> TopicDescription<nav_msgs/Odometry,
> cd5e73d190d741a2f92e81eda573aca7>>>
> Jun 20, 2012 9:36:36 AM
> org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline
> WARNING: An exception was thrown by a
> user handler while handling an
> exception event ([id: 0x0190d6c5,
> /192.168.0.226:34639 :>
> 192.168.0.24/192.168.0.24:45757] EXCEPTION:
> java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException)
> org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException:
> java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
> at
> org.ros.internal.transport.ConnectionTrackingHandler.exceptionCaught(ConnectionTrackingHandler.java:73)
> at
> org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:432)
> at
> org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannelSink.exceptionCaught(AbstractChannelSink.java:52)
> at
> org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:302)
> at
> org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:317)
> at
> org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:299)
> at
> org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:216)
> at
> org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:274)
> at
> org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:261)
> at
> org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:349)
> at
> org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:280)
> at
> org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:200)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
> >   at
> > java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
> > Caused by:
> > java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
> >   at
> > org.ros.internal.message.DoubleArrayField.deserialize(DoubleArrayField.java:67)
> >   at
> > org.ros.internal.message.DefaultMessageDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultMessageDeserializer.java:47)
> >   at
> > org.ros.internal.message.MessageFieldType.deserialize(MessageFieldType.java:87)
> >   at
> > org.ros.internal.message.MessageFieldType.deserialize(MessageFieldType.java:27)
> >   at
> > org.ros.internal.message.ValueField.deserialize(ValueField.java:64)
> >   at
> > org.ros.internal.message.DefaultMessageDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultMessageDeserializer.java:47)
> >   at
> > org.ros.internal.transport.IncomingMessageQueue$Receiver.messageReceived(IncomingMessageQueue.java:66)
> ... 12 more

I hope someone could help shed some light on this. To the best of my knowledge, I've tracked it down to a message type error or something along those lines. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36861/message-type:-rosjava-subscriber-problem/) by [bgagnon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2657/bgagnon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I did never use rosjava but by looking at the code I noticed two things:

1. If the topic is odom, you probably don't need that "/" prefix. (but this should not be the issue here)
2. Try using nav_msgs.Odometry._TYPE as the message type for newSubscriber (note: the type, not the string! so remove the ""). The documentation says it should accept a String, but the example you posted works with std_msgs.String._TYPE as well.

If that does not help, it looks like someone else has similar problems (or even the same?): http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=121

Cheers
Felix

---

Originally posted by [Felix Kaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/2655/felix-kaser/) with karma: 318 on 2012-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-07-02**:
Felix is correct. This is issue 121. Star it to be notified when it is addressed.